# Session validation in Apache and Mod_JK

Tags: apache, validation, session, apache2, mod-jk

How apache or mod_jk validate a session is created or not ? and session is valid or not ? and Session id is valid or not ? How apache handles sessions ?

Answer (score 1):

Apache doesn't interfere (or do any "validation") with the JSESSIONID cookie at all. It simply propagates everything from the client to tomcat, and from tomcat back to the client.